# Singularity locus in terms of ideals.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, reference-request

Let $X$ be a smooth affine variety over a field, $Z\subset Y\subset X$ are closed (reduced) subvarieties. What are the possible ways to verify whether $Y$ is singular at $Z$ i.e. whether $Z$ is contained in the singularity locus of $Y$? I would prefer some conditions in terms of ideals that determine $Y$ and $Z$ in $X$; yet other criteria could also be useful.

Comment: Can't you compute the singular locus using the Jacobian criterion?

Comment: I would also like to know other possibilities.

Comment: You can always look at the dimension of the tangent space at the generic point of $Z$ of course too (ie, use the definition of regular local ring).  This can be done in terms of ideals of $Y$ and $Z$ certainly (ie localize at the prime ideal defining $Z$ in $O_X/I_Y$ and compute the dimension of $I_Z/I_Z^2$).  

If the field is of characteristic $p$, you can look at whether $F_* O_Y$ is a flat $O_Y$-module along $Z$ (Kunz's criterion).  
